# How to perform input validation without exceptions or redundancy

Tags: design, design-patterns, programming-practices, performance, validation

When I'm trying to create an interface for a specific program I'm generally trying to avoid throwing exceptions that depend on non-validated input.

So what often happens is that I've thought of a piece of code like this (this is just an example for the sake of an example, don't mind the function it performs, example in Java):

```
public static String padToEvenOriginal(int evenSize, String string) {
    if (evenSize % 2 == 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("evenSize argument is not even");
    }

    if (string.length() >= evenSize) {
        return string;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(evenSize);
    sb.append(string);
    for (int i = string.length(); i < evenSize; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

OK, so say that `evenSize` is actually derived from user input. So I'm not sure that it is even. But I don't want to call this method with the possibility that an exception is thrown. So I make the following function:

```
public static boolean isEven(int evenSize) {
    return evenSize % 2 == 0;
}
```

but now I've got two checks that perform the same input validation: the expression in the `if` statement and the explicit check in `isEven`. Duplicate code, not nice, so let's refactor:

```
public static String padToEvenWithIsEven(int evenSize, String string) {
    if (!isEven(evenSize)) { // to avoid duplicate code
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("evenSize argument is not even");
    }

    if (string.length() >= evenSize) {
        return string;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(evenSize);
    sb.append(string);
    for (int i = string.length(); i < evenSize; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

OK, that solved it, but now we get into the following situation:

```
String test = "123";
int size;
do {
    size = getSizeFromInput();
} while (!isEven(size)); // checks if it is even
String evenTest = padToEvenWithIsEven(size, test);
System.out.println(evenTest); // checks if it is even (redundant)
```

now we've got a redundant check: we already know that the value is even, but `padToEvenWithIsEven` still performs the parameter check, which will always return true, as we already called this function.

Now for `isEven` of course doesn't pose a problem, but if the parameter check is more cumbersome then this may incur too much cost. Besides that, performing a redundant call simply doesn't feel right.

Sometimes we can work around this by introducing a "validated type" or by creating a function where this issue cannot occur:

```
public static String padToEvenSmarter(int numberOfBigrams, String string) {
    int size = numberOfBigrams * 2;
    if (string.length() >= size) {
        return string;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
    sb.append(string);
    for (int i = string.length(); i < size; i++) {
        sb.append('x');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

but this requires some smart thinking and quite a large refactor.

*Is there a (more) generic way in which we can avoid the redundant calls to `isEven` and performing double parameter checking?* I'd like the solution not to actually call `padToEven` with an invalid parameter, triggering the exception.

---

With no exceptions I do not mean exception-free programming, I mean that user input doesn't trigger an exception by design, while the generic function itself still contains the parameter check (if just to protect against programming errors).

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the exception?  You can do that by making an assumption about what the actual size should be.  For example, if you pass in 13, pad to either 12 or 14 and just avoid the check altogether.  If you cannot make one of those assumptions, then you're stuck with the exception because the parameter is unusable and your function cannot continue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That - in my opinion - goes straight against the principle of least surprise as well as against the principle of fail fast. It's much like returning null if the input parameter is null (and then forgetting to handle the result correctly, of course, hello unexplained NPE).

Comment: Ergo, the exception.  Right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, OK, but in that case I'm back to the original problem. I think your solution is much in line with my `padToEvenSmarter`, i.e. go around the issue in the first place by using another design - whatever that may be.

Comment: Well, you're basically reaching for a generalized validation strategy at this point, since you're committing to exception-free programming.  In this generalized strategy, how do you intend to convey validation errors?  `return false`?  If that's the case, I'd say that an odd value presented to that function would `return false`.  It would have to be in its own validation function, of course, otherwise you wouldn't know why it returned false.  You could also potentially return an error code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not going to discuss this any further as it is going nowhere. You're extrapolating that I want to use exception-free programming, which I'm not. If you have an answer I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: Wait, what?  You did come here for advice, right?  What I'm saying (in my apparently not so subtle way), is that those exceptions are *by design,* so if you want to eliminate them, you probably ought to have a good reason.  By the way, I agree with amon: you probably shouldn't have a function that can't accept odd numbers for a parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51776/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: The chat basically included that I want to have exception free programming *when it comes to validating user input*. I think you can design against throwing exceptions when it comes to validating input. Robert pointed out that this will come with a penalty if you do (and it probably does).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: You have to remember that `padToEvenWithIsEven` *does not* perform validation of user input. It performs a validity check on its input to protect itself against *programming errors* in the calling code. How extensive this validation needs to be depends on a cost/risk analysis where you put the cost of the check against the risk that the person writing the calling code passes in the wrong parameter.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I do realize this. It seems however that I often need to have the same kind of check before if I want to avoid exceptions given that the input is not trusted. The check in the method is then just to avoid programming errors, but that's good enough of a reason to include it. My libraries often already include validation methods as the implementer usually understands validation better than the caller (and, as indicated, often you need to implement it anyway). *Most of the time* the additional call is not a real issue by the way - devs are usually asked to simply call twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the case of your example, the best solution is to use a more general padding function; if the caller wants to pad to an even size then they can check that themselves.

```java
public static String padString(int size, String string) {
    if (string.length() >= size) {
        return string;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
    sb.append(string);
    for (int i = string.length(); i < size; i++) {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you repeatedly perform the same validation on a value, or want to only allow a subset of values of a type, then [microtypes](http://www.michael-snell.com/2015/03/microtyping-in-java-revisited.html) / tiny types can be helpful. For general purpose utilities like padding this is not a good idea, but if your value plays some particular role in your domain model, using a dedicated type instead of primitive values can be a great step forward. Here, you might define:

```java
final class EvenInteger {
  public final int value;

  public EvenInteger(int value) {
    if (!(value % 2 == 0))
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("EvenInteger(" + value + ") is not even");
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Now you can declare

```java
public static String padStringToEven(EvenInteger evenSize, String string)
    ...
```

and don't have to do any inside validation. For such a simple test wrapping an int inside an object will likely be more expensive in terms of run time performance, but using the type system to your advantage can reduce bugs and clarify your design.

Using such tiny types can even be useful even when they perform no validation, e.g. to disambiguate a string representing a `FirstName` from a `LastName`. I frequently use this pattern in statically typed languages.

Comment: Doesn't your second function still thrown an exception in some cases?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, for example in case of null pointers. But now the main check – that the number is even – is forced out of the function into the responsibility of the caller. They can then deal with the exception in a manner they see fit. I think the answer focusses less on getting rid of all exceptions than getting rid of code duplication in validation code.

Comment: Great answer. Of course in Java the penalty for creating data classes is quite high (a lot of additional code) but that's more a problem of the language than the idea you've presented. I guess that you would not use this solution for all of the use cases where my problem would occur, but it is a good solution against overusing primitives or for edge cases where the cost of the parameter check is exceptionally hard.

Comment: Hmm, thinking of this, I see that the exception is now thrown by the constructor. Wouldn't I have the same issue?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If you want to do validation, you can't get rid of something like exceptions. Well, the alternative is to use a static function that returns a validated object or null on failure, but that has basically no advantages. But by moving the validation out of the function into the constructor, we can now call the function without the possibility of a validation error. That gives the caller all the control. E.g.: `EvenInteger size; while (size == null) { try { size = new EvenInteger(getSizeFromInput()); } catch(...){}} String result = padStringToEven(size,...);`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Duplicate validation happens all the time. For instance, before trying to close a door your may check if it's already closed, but the door itself will also not allow to be re-closed if it already is. There is just no way out of this, except if you always trust that the caller doesn't perform any invalid operations. In your case you may have a `unsafePadStringToEven` operation that doesn't perform any checks, but it seems like a bad idea just to avoid validation.

Answer (score 9):

As an extension to @amon's answer, we can combine his `EvenInteger` with what the functional programming community might call a "Smart Constructor" -- a function that wraps the dumb constructor and makes sure that the object is in a valid state (we make the dumb constructor class or in non-class based languages module/package private to make sure only the smart constructors are used). The trick is to return an `Optional` (or equivalent) to make the function more composable.

```java
public final class EvenInteger {
    private final int value;

    private EvenInteger(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static Optional<EvenInteger> of(final int value) {
        if (value % 2 == 0) {
            return Optional.of(new EvenInteger(value));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

We can then easily use standard `Optional` methods to write the input logic:

```java
class GetEvenInput {
    public Optional<EvenInteger> askOnce() {
        int size = getSizeFromInput();
        return EvenInteger.of(size);
    }

    public EvenInteger keepAsking() {
        return askOnce().orElseGet(() -> keepAsking());
    }
}
```

You could also write `keepAsking()` in a more idiomatic Java style with a do-while loop.

```java
Optional<EvenInteger> result;
do {
    result = askOnce();
} while (!result.isPresent());

return result.get();
```

Then in the rest of your code you can depend on `EvenInteger` with certitude that it really will be even and our even check was only ever written once, in `EvenInteger::of`.

Comment: Optional in general represents potentially invalid data quite well. This is analogous to a plethora of TryParse methods, which return both data and a flag indicating input validity. With complie time checks.

Answer (score 1):

Doing validation twice is a problem if the result of the validation is the same AND the validation is being done in the same class.  That is not your example. In your refactored code, the first isEven check that is done is an input validation, failure results in a new input being requested.  The second check is completely independent of the first, as it is on a public method padToEvenWithEven which can be called from outside of the class **and** has a different result (the exception).

Your problem is similar to the problem of accidentally identical code being confused for non-dry. You are confusing the implementation, with the design. They aren't the same, and just because you have one or a dozen lines that are the same, doesn't mean that they are serving the same purpose and can forever be consided interchangeable. Also, probably having your class do too much, but skip that as this is probably just a toy example...

If this is a performance issue, you can solve the problem by creating a private method, that doesn't do any validation, which your public padToEvenWithEven called after doing it's validation and which your other method would call instead. If it's not a performance issue, then let your different methods do the checks that they require to do their assigned tasks.

Comment: OP stated that the input validation is done to prevent the function throwing. So the checks are completely dependent and intentionally the same.

Comment: @DDrmmr: no, they aren't dependent.  The function throws because that is part of it's contract.  As I said, the answer is to create a private method does everything except throw the exception and then have the public method call the private method.  The public method retains the check, where it serves a different purpose--to handle unvalidated input.